# How can I use Python and PIL to draw a shape that would simulate how light/shadow is cast around shapes/objects from a point in a (2D) image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

What I have is a black and white image of shapes, e.g. [shapes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ybnz.png).

And I would like to be able to, for any given point within the (white/valid portion) image, put a circle representing a radius of light cast from a point, e.g. [points A & B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3PNe.png) and [radii A & B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwUQj.png).

From there, I would like to generate a shape/mask, that correctly displays where the light would be and where shadows would be cast, e.g. [cast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHHrE.png).

Finally, I would like to create a final mask of this shape, e.g. [final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bZKm.png).

The initial shape layouts, the points, and the 'light' radii for each point would all be variable.

Comment: I believe there is a lot of information online about this sort of thing. One popular method is called Raycasting, specifically in 2D. Some introductory material could be found in these links: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TOEi6T2mtHo https://thecodingtrain.com/CodingChallenges/145-2d-ray-casting.html https://www.sszczep.dev/blog/ray-casting-in-2d-game-engines/

A term to search could be "2D Raycasting"

Comment: @Cascades Thank you for the wording and direction. I'm trying to create a still image and not a game or anything interactive, but I might be able to apply something.

Comment: Indeed! Most (if not all) of those algorithms should be applicable to a still image too!